# Inserting DBNull value to a DataTable column before bulk copy

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a data table that I use for Bulk Copying into a SQL server Database: I define its columns as follows:

```
dt.Columns.Add("BaseID", typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("ContractID", typeof(DateTime));
dt.Columns.Add("TermID",typeof(Int32));
dt.Columns.Add("Price",typeof(Decimal));
dt.Columns.Add("PeakType",typeof(String));
```

Now the PeakType column could actually be a string or it could be null. So when I add rows to my data table I do this.

```
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
row["BaseID"] = baseID;
row["ContractDate"] = contractDate;
row["TermID"] = termID;
row["Price"] = price;
row["PeakType"] = peakType; //How would I assign If I want to assign DBNull?
```

How do I specify DBNull.Value if peakType is null so that my bulk copy would correctly insert a null in the column in the SQL server table

Comment: Have u tried `DBNull.Value` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `null coalescing operator`.

```
row["PeakType"] = peakType ?? DBNull.Value;
```

If `peakType` is null, it will use the correct DB null value.

Comment: Thanks. Unlike parametrized queries, I am not able to use Database specific datatypes to define the columns of the datatable(like `SqlDbType.Int`, `SqlDbType.NVarchar`) instead having to use the typeof. Is there a potential for a conflict during the bulk insert operation or will the ints and the decimals and the strings correctly map onto ints and numeric and nvarchars of the database column?

Comment: @Sai You should be safe if the C# types you are feeding in the columns  are equivalent to the column type defined in SQL. You'll just need to test to make sure. Sorry, if that doesn't really help.

Comment: No.It does. Thanks. Just needed a word of confirmation. Also that is one of the reasons why I defined the `datatypes` of the data columns so any error due to the `datatype` mismatch gets caught before even there is an attempt insert rogue values into the DB.

Comment: using core5 I needed to add an (object) cast like:
row["PeakType"] = peakType ?? (object)DBNull.Value;